# object property name from another object value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, object

ok, so, we have the option to do this:

`var test ='name';`

`var obj[test] ='my name';`

So this is actually:

`var obj['name']='my name';`

right?

**Now for the question:**

how do I do :

`var test = 'name';`

`obj.test ='my name';`

so that when I output `obj.name` it returns `'my name'` ?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you're already doing with `obj[test]`?

Comment: Why do you want to use dot notation over bracket notation at this context?

Comment: hmm, not sure, is it?

Comment: am I confusing objects with arrays or what?

Comment: Why don't you *try it and find out?*

Comment: Array access notation and dot notation are interchangeable - [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/Emissary/uxwat8ey/).